# ZMQ - forwarding request between sockets or one-time proxy

Tags: zeromq

I'm struggling with connecting two sockets:

- frontend (ROUTER) - which handles clients request and forward them to backend
- backend (ROUTER)  - which receives request from frontend and deals with them with the use of number of workers ( which require some initialization, configuration etc).

The server code looks like this:

```
void server_task::run() {
    frontend.bind("tcp://*:5570");
    backend.bind("inproc://backend");

    zmq::pollitem_t items[] = {
        { frontend, 0, ZMQ_POLLIN, 0 },
        { backend, 0, ZMQ_POLLIN, 0}
    };

    try {
        while (true) {
            zmq::poll(&items[0], 2, -1);
            if (items[0].revents & ZMQ_POLLIN) {
                frontend_h();
            }

            if (items[1].revents & ZMQ_POLLIN) {
                backend_h();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (std::exception& e) {
        LOG(info) << e.what();
    }
}
```

`frontend_h` and `backend_h` are handler classes, each having access to both sockets.

The question is:
**Considering synchronous execution of `frontend_h()` and `backend_h()` how can I forward the request dealt in `frontend_h()` to `backend_h()`?**

I tried to simply re-send the message using backend socket like that:

```
void frontend_handler::handle_query(std::unique_ptr<zmq::message_t> identity, std::unique_ptr<zmq::message_t> request) {
    zmq::message_t req_msg, req_identity;
    req_msg.copy(request.get());
    req_identity.copy(identity.get());

    zmq::message_t header = create_header(request_type::REQ_QUERY);
    backend.send(header, ZMQ_SNDMORE);
    backend.send(message);
}
```

But it stucks on `zmq::poll` in `run()` after the execution of `handle_query()`.

Answer (score 0):

### Stucks on `zmq::poll()`?

Your code has instructed the `.poll()` method to block, exactly as documentation states:

> If the value of timeout is -1, `zmq_poll()` shall block indefinitely until a requested event has occurred...

---

### How can I forward the request?

It seems pretty expensive to re-marshall each message ( +1 for using at least the `.copy()` method and avoiding re-packing overheads ) once your code is co-located and the first, receiving handler, can request and invoke any appropriate method of the latter directly ( and without any `Context()`-processing associated efforts and overheads.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Avoiding forwarding the request was how i eventually dealt with the issue - I simply merged two handlers into one :) Please check the comment on stucking on `zmq::poll` - what i did not get is why it blocks after successful `backend.send()` in `handle_query()` - to my understanding there is message waiting to be received on `backend` socket.